# Refreshing to the data posted page after database insertion in php

Tags: javascript, php

Suppose I have three pages in php: Page1, Page2 and Page3.

1. Page1 has a link (anchor tag) with a variable. Suppose in the anchor tag href is like-
   **`href="Page2.php?id='$myid'"`**, where **`$myid`** has been posted in a variable **`id`** to the Page2.php if I click that link.
2. In the Page2.php I have a variable suppose **`$newid`** where I am storing the **`id`** variable (i.e. posted from Page1.php) using GET. It is like-
   **`$newid=$_GET['id'];`** . In this page I am posting some input data to Page3.php using a submit button.
3. In Page3.php, my posted data are inserted to my database (`mySql`) correctly.

Now my question is, after successful insertion of data to the database in Page3.php, how can I revert back to Page2.php since there is a variable **`id`** from Page1.php (**`$newid=$_GET['id'];`**) using a javascript message box. Even I have stored that `$newid` to a `SESSION` variable also in Page2. Please help.

Comment: echo '<script type="text/javascript">
           window.location = "localhost/id="'$_session['ID']'"
      </script>';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to **manipulate** the PHP variable in JavaScript or run logic against it, I would recommend making use of the HTML DOM itself as an intermediary point.

First, **echo** the PHP variable somewhere on the page:

```
<span id="php">
  <?php echo $newid; ?>
</span>
```

This output location can be **hidden** with CSS if need be.

```
#php {
  display: none;
}
```

Then, target the element with JavaScript:

```
var id = document.getElementById('php').innerHTML;
```

You can then manipulate the variable as you would like, running conditional logic, and redirecting accordingly:

```js
var id = document.getElementById('php').innerHTML;
if (id == 2) {
  // Logic triggers
  window.location = "page1.php?id=" + id;
}
```

```html
<span id="php">2</span>
```

The above example will pass the `id` parameter as `$_GET` to page 1.

However, it's important to note that [**`$_SESSION`**](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.session.php) data persists **between** pages, so you could always just use `$_SESSION['id']` directly, from **any** of your pages.

Hope this helps! :)